# Does the picture of the robots show a message?

Tags: discussion, robots, captcha

Hi

This post refers to the human verification image from superuser.com [which can be found here](https://superuser.com/captcha)

I just typed out the 0 and 1's from the new picture.

I think I may of missed a few as it was not 100% clear on some of the creases.

Anyway, It was not divisible by 8, so I added a few 0's to the end, I came up with -

```
00100110011000010110110101110000001110110010011000100011001100010011100000110111001110110010011001110001011101010110111101110100001110110010011000100011001100010011011100111001001110110110101100111101001101000110001001101100001001100010001100110001001110000011100000111011001001100010001100110001001101110011011100111011001001100010001100110001001101110011010000111011001011100001011000100110001000110011001000110001001101110011101100100110001000110011000100110110001100110011101100010000
```

And when I translated it, I came up with

```
&amp;&#187;&quot;&#179;k=4bl&#188;&#177;&#174;.&#217;&#163;
```

I am probably wrong (especially as I am half sleep, 4:30AM and asking a stupid question!), but I think I have come across something similar years ago when working with encoded JavaScript... just off by a few characters in a few places.

Anyway, Is it just random and I wasted my time (but had 5 mins of fun) looking in to this, or is it a message?

Comment: What picture of the robots?

Comment: had no idea meta had a different one, trying to find the one from superuser.com

Comment: Here's a link for easy viewing: http://superuser.com/captcha

Comment: The picture can be found here, editing original post - http://superuser.com/captcha

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what I transcribed from the image.

```
001001101011101100100010101
10011011010110011110100110100
01100010011101100101
1110010110001101
0111000101110000101101
101100110100011001
```

```
0010 0110 1011 1011 0010 0010 1011
0011 0110 1011 0011 1101 0011 0100
0110 0010 0111 0110 0101
1110 0101 1000 1101
0111 0001 0111 0000 1011 0110
1100 1101 0001 1001
```

```
26bb22b
36b3d34
62765
e58d
7170b6
cd19
```

```
26 bb 22 b3 6b 3d 34 62 76
5e 58 d7 17 0b 6c d1 90
```

```
&»"³k=4bv^X×lÑ
```

I think it is just some random data.

Comment: Too bad :(

Comment: Many thanks, have to makr you as the answer as you went to the extra effort!

Answer (score 6):

The picture is that of a homeless robot (really a robot protester), which was [posted to digg](http://digg.com/comedy/Homeless_Robot_PIC) awhile back. The message itself is gibberish, quite to the detest of diggers everywhere.